# Swift package manager - Bundle.module alongside Bundle(for:)

Tags: swift, frameworks, resources, swift-package-manager

I have an external library where I should access embedded resources. This library should be accessible via SPM as well as framework (direct linking, Carthage or Cocoapods for example).

The problem is to access these resources, I must call `Bundle.module` when the library is used as a swift package and `Bundle(for:)` when used as a framework.

Is there a mean to check if I'm compiling the library as a swift package or as a framework, like a preprocessor condition maybe ?

Answer (score 3):

`Bundle.module` will be synthesized with internal access level whether your package contains any resources. It's only visible when opening the `Package.swift` manifest file, trying to access it in the other ways results in an error.
Swift Package Manager doesn't depend on a `.xcodeproj` so you're just good to go.

Cocoapods, Carthage doesn't have that favor so you have to synthesize your own `Bundle.module`, here is a solution.

```
//
//  Bundle+Resource.swift
//  DateTimePicker
//
//  Created by Duy Tran on 10/9/20.
//

import Foundation

private class MyBundleFinder {}

extension Foundation.Bundle {
    
    /**
     The resource bundle associated with the current module..
     - important: When `DateTimePicker` is distributed via Swift Package Manager, it will be synthesized automatically in the name of `Bundle.module`.
     */
    static var resource: Bundle = {
        let moduleName = "DateTimePicker"
        #if COCOAPODS
        let bundleName = moduleName
        #else
        let bundleName = "\(moduleName)_\(moduleName)"
        #endif
        
        let candidates = [
            // Bundle should be present here when the package is linked into an App.
            Bundle.main.resourceURL,

            // Bundle should be present here when the package is linked into a framework.
            Bundle(for: MyBundleFinder.self).resourceURL,

            // For command-line tools.
            Bundle.main.bundleURL,
        ]

        for candidate in candidates {
            let bundlePath = candidate?.appendingPathComponent(bundleName + ".bundle")
            if let bundle = bundlePath.flatMap(Bundle.init(url:)) {
                return bundle
            }
        }
        
        fatalError("Unable to find bundle named \(bundleName)")
    }()
}
```

It seems many developers are looking for a solution, I am going to publish a Medium article for help.

Comment: You can have a look at this merge request to have a closer look https://github.com/itsmeichigo/DateTimePicker/pull/104/files